# Cannot get data with onItemClickListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, onitemclicklistener

I want to onItemClick the list view and got to DetailsPage to show the details, but it get me the null.
The item in `ListView` is  image url, name and address.
The item in DetailsPage is image url, name, address, contact and category.

[Image of the view on my phone when get null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5PAM.jpg)

This is my ListViewPage

```
public class ImageListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
private List<ImageUpload> imgList;
private ListView lv;
private ImageListAdapter adapter;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_list);
    imgList = new ArrayList<>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewImage);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait loading list image...");
    progressDialog.show();

    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(WorkshopsInfoActivity.FB_DATABASE_PATH);

    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ImageUpload img = snapshot.getValue(ImageUpload.class);
                imgList.add(img);
            }
            adapter = new ImageListAdapter(ImageListActivity.this, R.layout.image_item, imgList);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailsOfWorkshops.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}}
```

This is my DetailsPage

```
public class DetailsOfWorkshops extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
List<ImageUpload> listImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details_of_workshops);
    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(WorkshopsInfoActivity.FB_DATABASE_PATH);
    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ImageUpload img = dataSnapshot.getValue(ImageUpload.class);

            String name = img.getName();
            String address = img.getAddress();
            String contact = img.getContact();
            String category = img.getCategory();


            final TextView textViewDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            String string = "Name: " + name + "\nAddress: " + address + "\nContact: " + contact + "\nCategory: " + category + "\n\n";
            textViewDetails.setText(string);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You send nothing to the details class:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailsOfWorkshops.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Try using this:

```
YourClass item = (YourClass) adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext().this, DetailsOfWorkshops.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("valueName", value);
intent.putExtra("MyPackage", bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: sorry, i still can't get it. Is it something wrong with the code in my DetailsPage?

Comment: The problem sir is that you don't send anything from ImageListActivity to DetailsPage activity to indicate which item is gonna be displayed. Please do just like Rajesh guy above and see the different.

Answer (score 0):

We need to send some data from ActivityOne to ActivityTwo through intent then access that data in ActivityTwo and set it to desired textview.

Check below code in ActivityOne.

```
public class ImageListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
public List<ImageUpload> imgList;
private ListView lv;
private ImageListAdapter adapter;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_list);
    imgList = new ArrayList<>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewImage);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait loading list image...");
    progressDialog.show();

    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(WorkshopsInfoActivity.FB_DATABASE_PATH);

    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ImageUpload img = snapshot.getValue(ImageUpload.class);
                imgList.add(img);
            }
            adapter = new ImageListAdapter(ImageListActivity.this, R.layout.image_item, imgList);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            ImageUpload itemData = imgList.get(i);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailsOfWorkshops.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", itemData.getName());
            intent.putExtra("address", itemData.getAddress());
            intent.putExtra("contact", itemData.getContact());    
            intent.putExtra("category", itemData.getCatogory());    
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}}
```

Check out some changes in ActivityTwo

```
public class DetailsOfWorkshops extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
List<ImageUpload> listImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details_of_workshops);

    String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    String address = getIntent().getStringExtra("address");
    String contact = getIntent().getStringExtra("contact");
    String category = getIntent().getStringExtra("category");


    TextView textViewDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    String string = "Name: " + name + "\nAddress: " + address + "\nContact: " + contact + "\nCategory: " + category + "\n\n";
    textViewDetails.setText(string);

    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(WorkshopsInfoActivity.FB_DATABASE_PATH);
    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ImageUpload img = dataSnapshot.getValue(ImageUpload.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}}
```

Hope this helpful.

@Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

Try onItemSelected listener instead of onItemClick listener this will give you the position which can help you get the specific object whose data you want
Then you can send extras with proper value

```
        ImageUpload itemData = imgList.get(pos);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
        DetailsOfWorkshops.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", itemData.getName());
        intent.putExtra("address", itemData.getAddress());
        intent.putExtra("contact", itemData.getContact());    
        intent.putExtra("category", itemData.getCatogory());    
        startActivity(intent);
```

OnClick listener works for the whole view instead of a particular elements byt OnSelected gives the position of the item you selected on the listView